# Is there a more efficient way to compute this coefficient matrix?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an expression, $V(x_i)$ which is a function that is quadratic in the real-values entries of three $N\times N$ matrices, $x_i, i= 1,..3$. This $V(x_i)$ is a long, complicated expression,

\begin{align}
V(x_i)=\operatorname{Tr}(-2 ix_{1} x_{2}+2 ix_{2} x_{1}-\dotsm
\end{align}

the details of which are not critical to my question.

I want to numerically extract a matrix of coefficients appearing in $V(x_i)$ in a particular way. Specifically, I want to construct the matrix $K$ such that

\begin{align}
V\left(x_{i}\right) \equiv Y^{T} K Y
\end{align}

where $Y$ is a $3N^2$ dimensional vector that contains the entries of each of the $x_i$ matrices. I assign the entries of the $x_i$ matrices in order of their diagonals, starting with the main diagonal of all three and then following with the off-diagonals. Here's an example of what I'm describing, for $N = 2$. Here I'm reusing the $x_i$ notation to label the matrix elements rather than the three matrices.

$$\left(\begin{array}{ll}x_{1} & x_{7} \\ x_{10} & x_{2}\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ll}x_{3} & x_{8} \\ x_{11} & x_{4}\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}x_{5} & x_{9} \\ x_{12} & x_{6}\end{array}\right), \rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{c}x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ \vdots \\ x_{11} \\ x_{12}\end{array}\right)$$

and for $N = 3$:
$$\left(\begin{array}{lll}
x_{1} & x_{10}& x_{22} \\ 
x_{16} & x_{2}& x_{11}\\ 
x_{25} & x_{17}& x_{3}
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{lll}
x_{4} & x_{12}& x_{23} \\ 
x_{18} & x_{5}& x_{13}\\ 
x_{26} & x_{19}& x_{6}
\end{array}\right),
\left(\begin{array}{lll}
x_{7} & x_{14}& x_{24} \\ 
x_{20} & x_{8}& x_{15}\\ 
x_{27} & x_{21}& x_{9}
\end{array}\right)
 \rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ \vdots \\ x_{26} \\ x_{27}
\end{array}\right)$$

I'm working in MATLAB and the approach I've taken is to first define the expression $V(x_i)$ symbolically, and then take compute the Hessian matrix of the expression. MATLAB has a built-in function, `hessian(V, Y)` which performs this computation. I construct $Y$ separately, by looping over the diagonals of the $x_i$ and assigning them to the vector $Y$.

This procedure becomes very slow as $N$ grows. My question is about my use of `hessian` as this seems to be what takes most of the computing time. Is there a more computationally efficient approach to the construction of this matrix $K$?

Comment: I would like to help you (I have some practice with Matlab), but I am not certain to understand what kind of generalisation you need. For example, when $N=3$ what woule be the order ? Couldn't it be achieved by succesive applications of the **vec** operator (I mean by that the fact that if $A$ is a matrix, its **vec**torization is $A(:)$).

Comment: I've edited the question to try and clarify the generalisation. However the ordering isn't the most important aspect of this. I'm more interested in the potential alternatives to `hessian`.

Comment: If you differentiate $V$ once w.r.t. all variables, you'll end up with a linear system of equations: $\frac{dV}{dx} = 2 K Y$ in the symbolic variables $Y.$ Most symbolic toolboxes allow you extract [the coefficients of a symbolic linear system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.equationstomatrix.html;jsessionid=fb884f49fc07d5453b72c70b0214). I have no idea how efficient that is, but it is simpler. The coefficients you extract would equal $2 K.$

Comment: Why not write a little algorithm that collects the right diagonals and subdiagonals "at the right time" by using diag(A,k) with $k=1$ for example for the immediate upper diagonal entries ?

Comment: Each term in $V(x)$ can be evaluated as an elementwise/Hadamard product followed by summation. Since there are 3 matrices, there are only 6 ways to pair them up, and the total computational effort is ${\cal O}(6N^2)$.  By converting it into a quadratic form with $K\in{\mathbb R}^{3N^2\times 3N^2}$ the computational effort balloons to ${\cal O}(9N^4)$. So of course it's going to be slow, the whole approach is computationally inefficient.